# Notepad++ editor not preserving program formatting

Tags: notepad++

I was trying to edit my code through Notepad++ editor. But whenever i save my code after editing it am losing the lines formatting (on its place) whenever i open it again.

like... when i save like the following and close...

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

when i open again am getting like this...

```
 <html><head>       <title></title>      </head>      <body>      </body>     </html>
```

Can someone help me to get rid of this issue ? am i missing any setting there ?

Comment: Check the following, go to `Edit -> EOL Conversion`. I hope it's set on `Windows Format`

Comment: yes it is on Windows Format. Still the issue exists...!

Comment: Can you let us know what you are seeing if you enable the option `View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters`? (before saving and after when reopening)

Answer (score 0):

I could not even find a setting to turn line breaks off so I would recommend just reinstalling notepad++. Also a weird file type could also make the structure change on save. So make sure it is .html for this kind of thing. Let me know if you are still having problems.

Comment: i have reinstalled it... still the issue exists...!