# Notepad++ Formatting Issue

Tags: python, formatting, notepad++, jython, carriage-return

I have an issue, I am working on a jython project while editing it with Notepad++.  I'm having an issue where I save the file, open it in normal notepad.exe and the file comes out completely different to how i edited it on Notepad++.  It seems to be that wherever I pressed Enter for a new line, notepad++ formatted it to have a few spaces and the whole 150+ line code is word wrapped around five lines of carriage returns.

Any idea how I can fix this?  I figure it's in settings but I don't know how to google for it and don't want to try *every* option until it works as notepad++ is quite feature rich!

Comment: How is it unclear even when I answered my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out myself!  `Edit > EOL conversion > Windows Format` Thanks ME!  No, wait, credit goes to: [this guy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622066/notepad-editor-not-preserving-program-formatting)

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, you should close as such or delete it.

Comment: He can't because other question has no accepted answer.